# Where can I find the file PHP is fetching text/table from?

Tags: php, html, google-chrome-devtools

I recently inherited a website with a horrible file structure.  I need to update some content (text) but I can’t find where it is being defined. The database table does not have the information, so I'm guessing the text is being defined elsewhere. Is there a tool or "trick" in Chrome Dev Tools to find the content source? Your help is much appreciated!

***Snippet from PHP File:

```
<div id="product_wrapper" class="add-bottom30">
      <div class="columns sixteen">
              <div class="columns twelve add-bottom60 catalogue">
                    <!-- Pager -->
                                 <?php include('sql-' . $_SESSION['lang'] . '/promos.php');?>

              </div>
              <div class="columns four side">
               <h5 style="margin-bottom:25px;">FLYERS</h5>
                    <ul>

                        <li style="background-color:#0065a4;">
                            <a href="download-file.php?file=<?php echo 'doc-' . $_SESSION['lang'] . '/flyers/Storage-April-2016.pdf&&type=pdf' ?>"><?php echo flyer_jet_2016; (where the text I need to change lives) ?></a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"><!-- ClearFix --></div>
             </div>
        </div>
```

*** Snippet from source code ("View Source" in Chrome):

```
       <div class="columns four side">
               <h5 style="margin-bottom:25px;">FLYERS</h5>
                    <ul>

                        <li style="background-color:#0065a4;">
                            <a href="download-file.php?file=doc-eng/flyers/JET-Storage-April-2016.pdf&&type=pdf"><span class="icon" data-icon="(" style="color:#fff;margin-bottom:15px;"></span><br>Tool Storage<br>Solutions 2016</a>
                        </li>

                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"><!-- ClearFix --></div>
             </div>
```

Comment: You could `grep` the code base. You can't view PHP source in chrome. Try `grep 'flyer_jet_2016' -r .` from the root of your code base.

Comment: Is there really no `$` before `flyer_jet_2016`? If not, look for `define('flyer_jet_2016, '<span class="icon"...>')`; somewhere. If there is, look for code that assigns to `$flyer_jet_2016`.